# Error Processes en Laravel para un archivo Python

Tags: php, python, laravel

lo que quiero es ejecutar un archivo python desde Laravel, y para eso quiero usar process así:

```
$result = Process::run('python readSitemaps.py');

return $result->errorOutput();
```

Y me aparece:

```
"python" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

El problema es que ponga lo que ponga en el proceso me aparece el mismo error. Si colocará el ejemplo de la documentación de Laravel

```
$result = Process::run('ls -la');

return $result->output();
```

Me aparece que "ls" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo. Que creen que este sucediendo?

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo? Si es Windows, `ls` no existe, en su lugar prueba con `'dir /a-d'`. Si es el caso, revisa que `C:\la\ruta\de\python` esté en el [PATH](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+python+path) del sistema.

Comment: @aeportugal Es Windows y 'dir /a-d' si funciona, aunque python sigue sin funciona, ya revise el path y si me aparece la ruta de python. El gran problema sería porque python no me corre, si corriendo el archivo directamente va bien